# GitHub dependabot for a library inside a yml file

Tags: github-actions, jib, dependabot, maven-jib

### Introduction

I'm currently working on a project that automatically containerizes a java project with JIB.

GitHub project [link](https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/jib-container-publish.yml).

### Problem

The LIB library is implicitly used inside the YAML file, like this :

```yaml
    - name: Build JIB container and publish to GitHub Packages
      run: |
        if [ ! -z "${{ inputs.module }}" ]; then
          MULTI_MODULE_ARGS="-am -pl ${{ inputs.module }}"
        fi

        if [ ! -z "${{ inputs.main-class }}" ]; then
          MAIN_CLASS_ARGS="-Djib.container.mainClass=${{ inputs.main-class }}"
        fi

        mvn package com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:3.2.1:build \
        -Djib.to.image=${{ inputs.REGISTRY }}/${{ steps.downcase.outputs.lowercase }}:${{ inputs.tag-name }} \
        -Djib.to.auth.username=${{ inputs.USERNAME }} \
        -Djib.to.auth.password=${{ inputs.PASSWORD }} $MULTI_MODULE_ARGS $MAIN_CLASS_ARGS
      shell: bash
```

When the new version of JIB is released my dependabot configuration doesn't update the YAML file.

[Configuration of the Dependabot](https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/jib-container-publish.yml/blob/main/.github/dependabot.yml) :

```yaml
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: github-actions
    directory: '/'
    schedule:
      interval: weekly
```

### Question

Does someone know how to configure dependabot.yml for an implicitly declared library?
Or how to configure Dependabot.yml to automatically create an issue when a new JIB version is released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with *[hiden-dependency-updater](https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/Hiden-dependency-updater)*

Example of GitHub Workflow you can use:

```yaml
name: Update hidden dependencies

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 * * *'

jobs:
  update:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - uses: MathieuSoysal/hiden-dependency-updater@v1.1.1
        with:
          files: action.yml # List of files to update
          prefix: "com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:" # Prefix before the version, default is: ""
          suffix: ":build ."
          regex: "[0-9.]*"
          selector: "maven"
          github_repository: "GoogleContainerTools/jib"

      - name: Create Pull Request
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v4
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # You need to create your own token with pull request rights
          commit-message: update jib
          title: Update jib
          body: Update jib to reflect release changes
          branch: update-jib
          base: main
```

Answer (score 0):

[From the doc](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.4/code-security/dependabot/working-with-dependabot/keeping-your-actions-up-to-date-with-dependabot#example-dependabotyml-file-for-github-actions):

> The directory must be set to "/" to check for workflow files in
> .github/workflows.

```
  - package-ecosystem: "github-actions"
    # Workflow files stored in the
    # default location of `.github/workflows`
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      interval: "daily"
```

So: **try specifying a different directory**, as example:

```
  - package-ecosystem: "github-actions"
    # Workflow files stored in the
    directory: "."
    schedule:
      interval: "daily"
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!

I try it, but it didn't work: https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/jib-container-publish.yml/commit/9ffac1db7ada2c7cb90f3625748c5300374b8885

Do you know what? Or do you have another suggestion?

Comment: double check if you see a `dependabot` section at this url https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/jib-container-publish.yml/network/updates

Comment: I checked again, and I forced the Dependabot checking. But the dependabot doesn't update the Maven library inside the actions.yml.